# How do we continue to communicate with the assistant in a same stream?

Tags: grpc

https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-cpp

In run_assistant_text.cc with follow step we can only make a communicate with assistant

```
std::shared_ptr<ClientReaderWriter<AssistRequest, AssistResponse>> stream(std::move(assistant->Assist(&context)));
stream->Write(request);
stream->Read(&response)
```

In the example we can only write a request in the stream. 
Can we write muilt-request on the stream? like fllowing step:

```
std::shared_ptr<ClientReaderWriter<AssistRequest, AssistResponse>> stream(std::move(assistant->Assist(&context)));
stream->Write(request1);
stream->Read(&response1)
stream->Write(request2);
stream->Read(&response2)
```

Comment: please provide some working code in the form of a [mre].

Comment: as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!  You can call stream->Write multiple times and/or put stream->Write in a loop if you like.

It would be a good idea to check the status of stream->Read to make sure you have read everything.